# Vue js how to get the value of option-value and pass it in @click

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Sorry, but I'm new in vue js. How to get the value of option-value in q-select . I pass the 'department_id' in my functions. I am using quasar. When I run this, it show undefined.
What is the correct way to pass and show the data?

```
<div class="col-3">
                <q-select 
                v-model="model" 
                :options="branches"
                multiple
                use-chips
                option-value="department_id"
                option-label="full_branchdept_name"
                label="Branch Department"
                class="select-branch-department"
                outlined dense />

            </div>
            <!-- :options="[]" -->
            <div class="col-9 q-mb-md">
                <!-- <div class="float-right">
                    <q-btn label="Generate from all device" class="bg-custom-orange text-capitalize text-white"></q-btn>
                </div> -->
                <div class="float-left">
                    <q-btn color="primary"
                    class="fetch-branch-department"
                    label="FETCH" 
                    @click="showFilteredEmployees(department_id)"
                    />
                </div>
```

my vue:

```
methods: {
    showFilteredEmployees(department_id){
console.log(department_id); // i get undefined 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see in your code, you have chosen a `multiple` selection input. So, you must traversal your `model` to get the selected `department_id`s.

On the other hand, for the `@click="showFilteredEmployees(department_id)"` you don't need to pass the `department_id` neither your `model` variable. It should be just `@click="showFilteredEmployees"`. Just consider that your `model` variable will be available in all the scope of your component, and accessible trough the `this` object.

For instance, a working code could be as follow:

```
<template>
  <div class="col-3">
    <q-select
      v-model="model"
      multiple
      use-chips
      :options="branches"
      option-value="department_id"
      option-label="full_branchdept_name"
      label="Branch Department"
      class="select-branch-department"
      outlined
      dense
    />
  </div>
  <div class="col-9 q-mb-md">
    <div class="float-left">
      <q-btn
        color="primary"
        class="fetch-branch-department"
        label="FETCH"
        @click="showFilteredEmployees"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

For the method:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      model: [],
      branches: [
        { department_id: "1", full_branchdept_name: "Department 1" },
        { department_id: "2", full_branchdept_name: "Department 2" }
      ]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    showFilteredEmployees() {
      const filteredEmployees = this.model.map(employee => employee.department_id);
      console.log(filteredEmployees);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used the Quasar framework, but by looking at your code department_id is the name of the property on options that you want to be the value on the select, so you probably want to change

```
@click="showFilteredEmployees(department_id)"
```

to

```
@click="showFilteredEmployees(model)"
```

as model will be the selected value on the q-select.